# How to compare feet/inches values in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have dimension string value stored in the following format: 0' 0"

I need a formula to check whether the value is greater than zero (0' 0"). Can anyone please advise what I need? I am just starting with Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Val()` function.

```
Val (str)
```

Arguments
`str` is a text string.

Returns
Fractional Number

Action
The `Val (str)` function reads a string containing Numbers (example: an address, phone number, or social security number) and converts them to a decimal value. `Val` stops reading the string when it finds the first character in the string that it finds that it cannot recognize as a number or as a space.

Comment: isn't it going to return the same for 0' 0" and 0' 1"?

Comment: You asked for a way to check if the value is greater than zero. 
Feet or Inches is not relevant for that question. 
If you do need to know feet or inches, use the instr() function to check if the field contains """" or "''"